# Shouldn't there be "from" instead of "to" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I read this sentence in a weekly magazine published by "The Hindu":

> However we may protest to the contrary, we do judge and remember a book by its cover, Covers decide if the reader will take the book to the sales counter or ditch it.

We take book from a sales counter not to a sales counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we take books **from** a book shelf, bring them **to** the counter to pay for them and then bring them home.

You are right, that after paying for them, we take them back from the counter (if they were placed there beforehand), but in the phrase above it is implied, that the cover decides, whether we want to buy the book and therefore need to take it to the counter first.

Comment: In theory, there is nothing ungrammatical about *from*. It could even make sense in some circumstances. (The book could be displayed **at** the sales counter as an impulse purchase—meaning that you can only take it **from** there.) But it's the least *likely* preposition.